# PHP - Validar si una fecha pasa por otra

Tags: php, date, diff

Sucede que tengo una tabla donde guardo registros de cosas que se van a hacer con un formato: tarea, fechaInicio, fechaFin

Ejemplo: Podar el césped, 2018-02-20, 2018-02-25

Lo que necesito es que no se puedan registrar en la BD tareas que esten sobre esa fecha o pasen por ella.

El primer caso ya lo solucione que es reportar una tarea con una fecha mayor o igual a la de inicio y que la fecha fin sea menor o igual a la del registro de la BD que se esta evaluando:

Así siguiendo el ejemplo anterior: **Podar el césped, 2018-02-20, 2018-02-25**

Si quiero registrar una tarea limpiar la piscina con fecha inicio 2018-02-21 no lo deja hacer.

El detalle esta cuando registro una tarea así:

Cambiar las bombillas, 2018-02-15, 2018-02-30

No he logrado poder identificar la forma de detectar que existen fechas dentro de este rango.

El cogido que estoy usando es este:

```
//datos enviados desde el form
$start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start));
$end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end));

//obtengo las tareas registradas a futuro en la BD
    $actualNovelties = $em->getRepository('RocketSellerTwoPickBundle:Novelty')->getRegisterVacationsNoveltiesByUser($payroll);

        // creo un flag para validar si existen registros en ese rango
        $flagSame = 0;

        //valido si existen datos en la variable
        if($actualNovelties != null){

            //recorro cada una de las tareas
            foreach ($actualNovelties as $actualNovelties){

                //convierto a timestamp las fechas de los registros de la BD
                $dateBegin =strtotime($actualNovelties->getDateStart()->format('Y-m-d'));
                $dateEnd = strtotime($actualNovelties->getDateEnd()->format('Y-m-d'));


                //valido si la fecha de inicio enviada desde el form se cruza con las fechas de la BD
                if ((strtotime($start) >= $dateBegin) && (strtotime($start) <= $dateEnd))
                {
                    // si cumple la condición incrementa el flag
                    $flagSame++;
                }

                //valido si la fecha fin enviada desde el form se cruza con las fechas de la BD
                if ((strtotime($end) >= $dateBegin) && (strtotime($end) <= $dateEnd))
                {
                    // si cumple la condición incrementa el flag
                    $flagSame++;
                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

No se que base uses, pero podrias usar SQL para crear un stored procedure que lo verifique, asi:

```
 IF  NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
          FROM tabla_fechas
         WHERE fecha_nueva_inicio BETWEEN fecha_inicio AND fecha_fin
            OR fecha_nueva_fin BETWEEN fecha_inicio AND fecha_fin
    ) THEN 
    INSERT INTO tabla_fechas(fecha_inicio,fecha_fin)VALUES(fecha_nueva_inicio,fecha_nueva_fin)
END IF;
```

Y llamarlo desde php

Comment: Gracias! Me es útil, aunque ahora ya lo he solucionado por el lado de PHP.

Comment: Si lo solucionaste marca el problema como solucionado

Comment: @FernandoLeón si solucionaste el problema, por favor escribe una respuesta explicando por qué ocurría y los pasos que seguiste para solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Como comentaba el detalle esta en que no hallaba como validar si una fecha se sobreponía a otra, así que complemente las validaciones dentro del for each así:

```
if((strtotime($start) <= $dateEnd) && (strtotime($end) >= $dateBegin)){
     $flagSame++;
}
```

Lo que esta ultima validación hace es:

Comprueba si la fecha de inicio que estan agregando desde el form es menor o igual a la fecha fin de los datos de la BD, tambien comprueba que la fecha fin ingresada del form sea mayor o igual a la fecha de inicio de los datos taridos de la BD.

Gracias!!!